# How to convert ES6 code to ES5 code on Run Time of Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-5, es5-compatiblity

I am getting one angular module details from API. The module is in ES6
i want to convert that module code into ES5 syntax.

[API Used for Module Response](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Dheerajprogrammer/38c0ca75bf50f6133aceb675a375cabc/raw/91a98e40dd4fc11afbcb5b2bae97a2caaaf0d3a1/app.mdule.ts)

i have tried `import { transform } from 'babel-core';` after installing the babel run time. but it is throwing error.

```
load() {
    fetch(url) // making the get request for loading the module response
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(source => {
// i want to convert this response to es5 standard. right now it is in es6
      });
  }
```

My expectation is to transpile es6 to es5 code, on run time of angular
component function.

Comment: Why? The typescript compiler does this for you if you configure it correctly. See the [typescript configuration docs](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration)

Comment: @Liam actually the response is in string form. I want to convert that string code. any suggesions on that ?

Comment: What does "in string form" mean?

Comment: Wait your loading an external library and then running it? That sounds like a code injection attack waiting to happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

and then:

```
import * as babel  from '@babel/core';

load() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then((source) => {
         return babel.transform(source, {
           presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
         });
      });
  }
```